# how do i get openscholar to work again

Tags: distributions

Im trying out drupal openscholar, and every time i change some setting 
(enabling  css agregation, enabling require.js) after installation, it stops serving js and css files till i reinstall even if i revert the setting. 
what could be going on? 
here are some errors:

```
Notice: Undefined index: os_default in drupal_theme_initialize() (line 100 of /var/www/html/dr20o32/includes/theme.inc).
Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in _drupal_theme_initialize() (line 145 of /var/www/html/dr20o32/includes/theme.inc).
Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in _theme_load_registry() (line 334 of /var/www/html/dr20o32/includes/theme.inc).
Notice: Undefined index: os_default in theme_get_setting() (line 1414 of /var/www/html/dr20o32/includes/theme.inc).
Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in theme_get_setting() (line 1451 of /var/www/html/dr20o32/includes/theme.inc).
Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in theme_get_setting() (line 1461 of /var/www/html/dr20o32/includes/theme.inc).
```

This is with drupal-7.20 , and openscholar 3.2.0, the same thing happens with 
drupal-7.22 and openscholar 3.4.1

this is what it looks like:
[image: http://imgur.com/OxjEGsT]

here are the permissions on sites/*/files

```
[default]3 ll *
total 52
-rw-rw-r--. 1 apache apache 23197 May 14 11:50 default.settings.php
drwxrwxr-x. 5 apache apache  4096 May 14 12:27 files  
-r--r--r--. 1 apache apache 23501 May 14 11:56 settings.php
[default]# ll files/
total 12
drwxrwxr-x. 2 apache apache 4096 May 14 12:31 css
drwxrwxr-x. 3 apache apache 4096 May 14 18:12 ctools
drwxrwxr-x. 2 apache apache 4096 May 14 12:02 styles
```

even the selinux contexts look ok.

Comment: apologies if this is obvious but you are flushing full cache several times after each of these operations, correct?

Comment: no i havent flushed the cache severally. is this documented anywhere? iv had trouble getting much docs.

Comment: but i did reboot the machine several times since.

Comment: Rebooting the machine won't touch the cache...you need to read the Drupal docs (not the open scholar docs) to understand how Drupal's aggregation works

Comment: well i cleared the cache about 10 times to no avail, still the problem persists.

Answer (score 0):

Disable css and js aggregation. If it helps, you have problem with `sites/*/files` directories and your php can't write to them.

Comment: the comments on my question seem not to answer it so probably this might be the line of inquiry i need to follow, i'v added some info n permissions , see edits

Comment: Info on permissions without a knowledge of a username:group Apache is actually using is hardly useful. Have you tried to disable aggregation?

Comment: yes, i have disabled it, it was the first thing i did, never helped a bit, even after clearing the cache.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to get started is with the latest release here: http://openscholar.harvard.edu/download We've already downloaded drupal, run the build script, and packaged everything up into a file for you to download.

Start with that, put it in a folder apache can see, and browse to install.php. If you get stuck, we're happy to help but you'll need to be specific.